# Setting up multiple alarms in Android

Tags: android, overriding, alarm, timepicker

When I make an alarm with the time picker the new one always overrides the previous one. I need help to make multiple alarms that override each other. I am using the following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent("class");

PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
DatePicker dpDate = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dp_date);
TimePicker tpTime = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tp_time);

int year = dpDate.getYear();
int month = dpDate.getMonth();
int day = dpDate.getDayOfMonth();
int hour = tpTime.getCurrentHour();
int minute = tpTime.getCurrentMinute();

GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, minute);
long alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm_time, operation);

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Alarm is set successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Obviously enough, here `PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` **all your alarms have an id = 0** (second parameter of your PendingIntent constructor), so the next one you set overrides the previous one. IDs must be **unique**. `Elementary, my dear Watson!`

Comment: and how do i edit my pending intent (new to android)

Comment: Put the whole code shown in a method. This method accepts an int as a parameter. This int is an id you pass (all ids you pass must be different, so either use an array of ints or a progressive number or some constants, an enum - it doesn't matter).